# PHP and mySQL, working with num_affected_rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

Now, the program is working fine ***to an extent***, in that when mysql_affected_rows is more than 0, it does indeed add the data to the new table and print out the relevant echo message.

However, when mysql_affected_rows = 0, I get nothing, no error message, but absolutely no output at all.

I've stripped the code back, do any of you have any idea, i've looked at brackets, and closing conditions etc and can't work out why!

**Code**

```
$query10 = ("SELECT p.surname, p.passNo, p.activeUntil FROM PASSENGER p WHERE p.activeUntil < DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 DAY)");
$result = mysql_query($query10);  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{       
    $surname =  $row['surname'];
    $passNo = $row['passNo']; 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO ARCHIVED_PASSENGER (surname, passNo) VALUES ('$surname', '$passNo')  ") 
        or die(mysql_error());  

    if (mysql_affected_rows()>0) {
        echo '<p>';
        echo "The number of rows affected by this update is:  ";
        echo mysql_affected_rows(); 
    }

    if  (mysql_affected_rows()<1) {     
        echo '<p>';
        echo "No records were affected. Taking you back to the control panel.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the deprecation process . Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: @Truth, although keeping up with best practice should always be encouraged, it doesn't help that, without exception, all the results on the 1st page of a google search for 'php mysql tutorial' only show how the use the mysql_* functions.  Indeed, even within the MySQL PHP 'book' (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php), there is no mention of the functions no longer being maintained

Comment: @ChrisW: Which is why I linked to both PDO and MySQLi's manual pages, plus added a good PDO tutorial.

Comment: what will happen if you use `else` above? something like `if (mysql_affected_rows()>0) ... else ...`.

Comment: @ChrisW: I haven't edited my comment, edited comment has a pencil icon next to it (like this one). Even though it's not official, it doesn't justify the use of an old, broken feature.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to add a `if($result != false && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)` just before the while loop. Like so:

```
$query10 = ("SELECT p.surname, p.passNo, p.activeUntil FROM PASSENGER p WHERE p.activeUntil < DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 DAY)");

$result = mysql_query($query10);  

if($result != false && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $surname =  $row['surname'];
        $passNo = $row['passNo']; 


        $query11 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ARCHIVED_PASSENGER (surname, passNo) VALUES ('$surname', '$passNo')  ") 
            or die(mysql_error());  

        if ($query11 != false && mysql_affected_rows()>0) {
            echo '<p>';
                echo "The number of rows affected by this update is:  ";
                echo mysql_affected_rows();
            echo '</p>';
        }

        if  ($query11 == false || mysql_affected_rows()<1) {     
            echo '<p>';
                echo "No records were affected. Taking you back to the control panel.";
            echo '</p>';
        }
    } else {
        //nothing was retrieved, give some error!
    }
 }
```